# Oracle APEX - handling APEX internal errors

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I am currently using `APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR` to display user-friendly error messages to the user and was wondering if defining application specific apex error handling function such as [this one](https://gerardnico.com/ide/apex/error_handling) would be beneficial in any way? Or should I stick with just adding `APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR` to my PL/SQL procedures?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different things with different purposes.

You might call `apex_error.add_error` to *add* an error to the stack when the user does something wrong, e.g. if you are writing custom validation in PL/SQL.

You might use a custom Error Handling Function to control what happens *when an error is raised*, e.g. to trap a particular APEX error and change how it is presented to the user.

You might do both, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is whenever error occurs, is to limit what is shown to the user, to show a user-friendly error message on the page. So my page calls a PL/SQL procedure and when exception occurs in that procedure I use apex_error.add_error to set a user-fiendly error message to be shown on my page

Comment: That should work fine. Personally I use an error mapping function that looks up an error code from a table (which in theory would also allow translations).

Comment: it works fine but I wanted to figure out whether I should do things differently, and, perhaps, use error handling function

Comment: Usually I don't - let APEX report the error and deal with it as a defect.